# How to cite if one mentions an author several times in a paragraph using APA7?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I have a short paragraph in my text where I summarize the research questions of an author. I begin with

> The goal of the author is ... ... leading to his research questions as stated now:

Now there follows an enumeration of the 2 research questions (direct citation in English, but with a German translation, since I write in German). At the end of the second item of the enumeration I cite (Author, Year, Page).

The latter was done because following guidelines I heard of, one must only put the citation as the last item and also one usually directly cites in English and translates to German rather than directly translating and paraphrasing it (no pages needed for citation).

Now the question: is that correct or should I only write (Page) at the end of the second item of the enumeration because following the introduction above, one knows that the quotes are taken from Author (Year)?

Thank you!